# Get tictok id from Url Regex issue

Tags: python, regex

Regex is not my strong suite but I am currently using this regex `(\/[\d]+)` to get the id from tictok urls.

```
https://m.tiktok.com/h5/share/usr/6641141594707361797.html
https://m.tiktok.com/v/6749869095467945218.html
https://www.tiktok.com/embed/6567659045795758085
https://www.tiktok.com/share/user/6567659045795758085
https://www.tiktok.com/trending?shareId=6744531482393545985
```

I get the id from all the links except the one with the shareId=xxxxxxxxxxx.
I modified my original regex to the following below and still not getting the id from the link with shareId=xxxxxxxxxxx. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
(?:|shareId=)(\/[\d]+)
```

Comment: Your regex says "a slash, followed by one or more digits". The last example TikTok URL doesn't have a slash before the digit. Your attempt at fixing it still has this problem.

Comment: @user2974907 please post an answer to your own question, using ceejayoz's hint. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Be sure to mention an online fiddle, perhaps this one: https://regexr.com/6t871

Comment: I used ceejayoz hint and fixed it but now its catching one of the digits in one of the names. See regex.       https://regex101.com/r/ppjnOF/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make the pattern specific for the tiktok urls in the question, and use a capture group for the digits:

```
https?://(?:m|www)\.tiktok\.com\b\S*?(?:/(?:use?r|v|embed)/|\bshareId=)(\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `https?://(?:m|www)\.tiktok\.com\b` Match the start of the urls
- `\S*?` Match optional non whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `(?:/(?:use?r|v|embed)/|\bshareId=)` Match one of `/usr/` `/user/` `/v` `/embed/`  `shareId=`
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f5B6B9/1).

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following regex. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q8BhId/1) for shown regex.

```
\bhttps?:\/\/(?:m|www)\.tiktok\.com\/.*\b(?:(?:usr|v|embed|user)\/|\?shareId=)(\d+)\b
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex here.

```
\bhttps?:\/\/         ##Mentioning word boundary to avoid partial matches for http/https followed by : 2 slashes.
(?:m|www)             ##In a non-capturing group matching m OR www
\.tiktok\.com\/       ##Followed by .tiktok.com
.*\b                  ##Doing greedy match followed by word boundary.
(?:                   ##Starting one non-capturing group here.
  (?:                 ##Starting one more non-capturing group here.
    usr|v|embed|user  ##matching usr OR v OR embed OR user here.
  )                   ##Closing previously opened non-capturing group here.
  \/                  ##Followed by a literal / here.
  |                   ##putting OR condition here.
  \?shareId=          ##matching ?ShareId= here.
)                     ##Closing firstly opened non-capturing group here.
(\d+)                 ##Creating one and only capturing group which has digits in it.
\b                    ##Followed by word boundary here to avoid partial matches.
```

Comment: @user2974907, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are working answers given already, but I want to suggest an elegant-looking solution:

```
([=/][\d]+)
```

The first set checks for either '=' or '/' symbol.
See https://regex101.com/r/9uNJZ1/1

Comment: You could write it as `[=/]\d+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
'''(?:\/|shareId=)\d+(?!.*\/)'''g
```

It matches either a slash `/` or `shareId=` followed one or more digits.

It then adds an extra check that there are no more slashes on that line - this way slashes in names won't match.

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/LhQXEt/1)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used the suggestions given and made the adjustments and got the following regex. see solution and link below. Thanks for all the help.

```
(?:|shareId=^)\d{19}
```

https://regex101.com/r/OY8B6h/1

Comment: You could write this as `\d{19}` because `shareId=^` will not match

Comment: Yeah, @The fourth bird is quite right. You could replace `shareId=^` with `shareId=ABC`, or with `DEF` -- each of those three is an expression that never appears in the supplied text. The only saving grace is the "match empty string" to the left of the `|` vbar. There is nothing in that non-matching group that is helping you at all, best to elide it. In general, for any letter X, if you write `X^` it is guaranteed to never match, since `^` caret specifically matches at start of string (or start of line).